# Python For Loop is executing to often

Tags: python, excel, loops, for-loop

I have 2 for-loops in python that check if 2 lists have the same value and if they have it should modify a cell value to create a excel depending on the for-loops.

Code:

```
    # Fill the Excel with the entryList Values
for i in range(0, len(entryList)):
    for j in range(0, len(entryListEKR)):
        component_number_cell = ws.cell(row=i + 2, column=1)
        component_number_cell.value = entryList[i]      
        if(entryList[i] == entryListEKR[j]):
            print(entryList[i] + entryListEKR[j])                                     
            component_EKR_cell = ws.cell(row=i + 2, column=2)                         
            component_EKR_cell.value = "Yes"               
            print("Yes" + str(i))                            
        elif(entryList[i] != entryListEKR[j]):      # here is the problem! 
            testList.append(entryList[i])


print(str(testList))
```

The problem is that the `if-clause` is setting the "**Yes**" correctly - so if the strings where matched and also places the "**Yes**" in the right line. BUT the `elif` or when I do it with `else` does not work for me.

I have noticed that there is probably a logically error I made while looping inside the loop because it seems that the outter loop is getting called to much...

If I say that the `elif` should set all to "**No**" if they dont match, then all my "**Yes**" from before are getting replaced except the last one. Because it is calling the loop to often hence overwritting it.
The Code in the `elif` is basically the same like it is in the if but just setting "**No**" instead of "**Yes**". If I `print(str(testlist))` then I see that every string is added like 14 times instead of once.

I have also checked the types in the `elif !=` to be sure that both have the same type, what they indeed do.

Does anyone see my mistake? - Thanks Faded

Comment: yeah because you compare for example  the first element of list 1 with every element in list 2. So if list 1 has 14 items and list 2 has 14 items. you compare item 1 of list 1 with all 14 items in list 2 and each time it doesnt match your appending to the temp list. then same again with item 2 and then 3 etc. Do you mean check item 1 in both lists match or not, check item 2 in both lists match or not etc? cause thats not what your currently doing

Comment: yeah but I cant figure out how to fix this - I think its just changing the "i" or "j" somewhere I guess

Comment: do you want to compare each item in list 1 to all other items in list 2? or you want to only match the items in list 1 with the same item in list 2

Comment: Basically I am looking if the 2 lists have the same componentnumber if yes then set "yes" in the excel and if not then it should set "no" in the list. Its about 200 Elements in the first list and like 15 with a "yes" and the rest should be "no"

Comment: but what i mean is lets say list1 item1 is "component x" are you expecting to only compare that to list2 item1? or you need to look for that in all the elements of list2?

Comment: Basically if list1 hast componentX and list2 also has it then set it Yes otherwise set it No. The answer below seems to fix my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing len(entryListEKR) is around 14 or 15? What your loops are doing is looping over every value of "entryList" and then during each value you are looping over "entryListEKR". I can help, however I need more explanation as to what you want and if the two lists have the same length? For now I'm taking a guess as what you need:

```
    # Fill the Excel with the entryList Values
for i in range(len(entryList)):
    count=0
    for j in range(len(entryListEKR)):
        component_number_cell = ws.cell(row=i + 2, column=1)
        component_number_cell.value = entryList[i]      
        if(entryList[i] == entryListEKR[j]):
            print(entryList[i] + entryListEKR[j])                                     
            component_EKR_cell = ws.cell(row=i + 2, column=2)                         
            component_EKR_cell.value = "Yes"               
            print("Yes" + str(i))                            
        elif(entryList[i] != entryListEKR[j] and count==0):      # here is the problem! 
            testList.append(entryList[i])
            count+=1


print(str(testList))
```

Also I would suggest learning a bit more about for loops in python, instead of looping over indexes you could loop over the elements themselves.

Edit: After reading your comments on your main post I think what you need is simply:

```
     # Fill the Excel with the entryList Values
for i in range(len(entryList)):
    component_number_cell = ws.cell(row=i + 2, column=1)
    component_number_cell.value = entryList[i]      
    if(entryList[i] in entryListEKR):
        #print(entryList[i] + entryListEKR[j])                                     
        component_EKR_cell = ws.cell(row=i + 2, column=2)                         
        component_EKR_cell.value = "Yes"               
        print("Yes" + str(i))                            
    else:      
        testList.append(entryList[i])


print(str(testList))
```

Comment: Alright this seems to work for me... I will check the data and accept the answer if it really did everything right. Thanks!

Comment: Okay so it seems to work - BUT the first match is not getting written correctly. The first Yes is a No - rest seems to work

Comment: I have added count += 1 before the first if now I have the first one too

Comment: Can you provide a minimum working example or excel sheet without any personal info? Are there multiple Yes values expected in the j loop? as if this is true your code will overwrite the values since the cell rows are based on the value of i perhaps try to include count in row? i.e. row=i+count+2

Comment: @yesIamFaded I've edited the main answer can you check if it's what you need?

Comment: Yeah that also seems to work I have 1 Value somewhere in the middle wich does not set the right value - but I have to look into it. Thanks im gonna accept it for now